# MongoDB structure for video genre's?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm working on an application using the YouTube API.  I am collecting data that i'm storing in MongoDB. I am hoping to get some tips on best practices for structuring the database and splitting the videos up by genres.

Is it best for me to create a new collection and Schema for each genre, or should I structure my Schema like below?

```
var vidSchema = new Schema({
  genre: String,
  title: String,
  artist: String,
  image: String,
  link: String,
  trackId: Number
});
```

I feel like I should be creating a new Schema for each genre so when pulling I don't have to sort through all the documents in order to find things from a specific genre.  On the other hand, there could be downsides in creating an entire new Schema that i'm not thinking about.  Any thoughts?

Comment: I sure like the less is more solution.  One schema, one collection.  Creating a new collection for each schema can be a hassle later.  Question. How may genre's can a particular YouTube Video have?  One or more than one?   This is getting mighty close to "its hard to do SQL with a non-SQL database storage system."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB can support a complex schema, in which one schema in this case vidschema, can contain to references to documents in other schema.

So you will need to create a new schema everytime you find a new genre for a video as such :

```
var genreSchema = new Schema({
genrename: String
})
```

your new vid schema

```
var vidSchema = new Schema({
title: String,
genre:{
type: Schema.ObjectId,
ref: 'genre'
},
morefields : String
})
```

it wont cause you problem, but it would enable you to use methods you would implement to create, get, update, & delete genre schema

Comment: This is very interesting.  I will have to do some more reading on it but I think this is what I'd like.  A reference in the main `vidSchema` to a separate `genreSchema` seems like a good way to do this. Thanks!